# Laravel 5 insert pivot table with attributes

Tags: php, laravel-5

I've been learning laravel for a few days now and I was hoping you guy's could help me.
I have the following table structure:

```
users
------
id


companies
------
id


company_user
------
company_id
user_id
owner
```

My User and Company models have functions specified like this:

### User Model

```
public function companies() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Company', 'company_user', 'company_id', 'user_id')->withPivot('owner');
}
```

### Company Model

```
public function users() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'company_user', 'company_id', 'user_id')->withPivot('owner');
}
```

For example when I save a company to a user like this:

```
User::find(1)->companies()->save(\App\Company::find(1));
```

The pivot table gets filled nicely, but the owner column doesn't get filled.
I can't find many online how to fill this column. Hope you guys can help me?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can pass additional data as second argument to `save()`:

```
User::find(1)->companies()->save(\App\Company::find(1), ['owner' => 'foo']);
```